# Rename a portion of a filename recursively throughout directory and sub directory

Tags: linux, bash, command

How can I make this command also execute throughout sub directories?

```
for filename in *foo*; do mv "$filename" "${filename//foo/bar}"; done
```

Comment: Have you tried, using the globstar pattern `**` to recurse into subdirectories like so: `**/*foo*`? You may have to enable this feature before you can use it: `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: Set the `globstar` option by `shopt -s globstar` and then replace the `*foo*` with `**/*foo*`.

Comment: Note, though, that you should check, whether this does what you expect, e.g. by putting an `echo` before the `mv`.

Comment: Like Xoozee said, or at least do a `mv -iv ....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to rename only the filename (last pathname component), not a inbetween subdirectory name. Then this task can be accomplished using `globstar` feature of bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for pathname in ./**/*foo*; do
    [[ -f $pathname ]] || continue
    basename=${pathname##*/}
    mv "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/${basename//foo/bar}"
done
```

Comment: That's true, and checking that you are renaming a file and not a directory would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Fravadona Fair enough

Comment: This did the trick, and yes it was for a filename rather than a directory name. Thank You!